# BASH - Extracting date from day

Tags: linux, bash, shell

just started working with BASH here and am currently am stuck with  extracting the date of each Wednesday in the current month....anybody able to help me shed some light here? cheers!

Comment: cal | awk 'NR>2{print $4}'

Comment: Could you show us a sample of the code you tried ? Here is a [potential usefull link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week) that shows the algorithm to determine the of the week based on the date

Comment: @soFan Nice! however this would need some tweaking to handle months where the 1st isn't a sunday (awk skips empty fields, so `$4` may be offset for the first week). For august, this script outputs `4 10 17 24 31` instead of `3 10 17 24 31`

Comment: Cheers guys, it managed to work when i did this cal | awk 'NR>2{print $4}' – but however i get the wrong results when i use ncal instead

Answer (score 1):

Try the following script (inspired from SoFan's comment) :

```
varY=2016;varM=8;varD=4; cal $varM $varY | sed 's/   / . /g' | awk -v f="$varD" 'NR>2{if ($f ~ "\.") {next;} {print $f}}'
```

**Explanation**:

- `varY=2016;varM=8;varD=4;` : parameters for the scrit. Respectively for Year, Month, and Day. Day can be `1 2 3 4 5 6 7` and by default correspond to `su mo tu we th fr sa`
- `cal $varM $varY` : displays the calendar for the `$varM` and `$varY` input paramenters. In this case :

  ```
      August 2016
  su mo tu we th fr sa
      1  2  3  4  5  6
   7  8  9 10 11 12 13  
  14 15 16 17 18 19 20  
  21 22 23 24 25 26 27  
  28 29 30 31
  ```

  As awk doesn't read empty fields, we'll have to convert the empty fields so that it can detect them.
- `sed 's/   / . /g'` : adds a `.` in the middle of every block of 3 spaces it encounters.

  ```
   .  August 2016 .   
  su mo tu we th fr sa
   .  1  2  3  4  5  6  
   7  8  9 10 11 12 13  
  14 15 16 17 18 19 20  
  21 22 23 24 25 26 27  
  28 29 30 31 .  .  .   
   .  .  .  .  .  .  .
  ```
- `awk -v f="$varD" 'NR>2{if ($f ~ "\.") {next;} {print $f}}'` :

  - `awk -v f="$varD"` : indicates you are reading the field number stored in the `$varD` variable
  - `NR>2` : indicates you are skipping the first 2 lines
  - `if ($f ~ "\.") {next;} {print $f}` : if the field is a dot, we skip it. Otherwise, we print it.

    ```
    3
    10
    17
    24
    31
    ```